# Most efficient way to have multiple toggle items on a page

Tags: javascript

If I've got multiple items that I want to change from a display of 'none', to a display of 'block', what's the most efficient way of doing it?

The JS I would use for a single item is below, but I imagine there are several on a page or site. Should I make use of function constructors somehow?

```
var sideNav = document.getElementById('sideNav');
var menuButton = document.getElementById('menuButton');

function toggle() {
    if(sideNav.style.display) {
        sideNav.style.display = '';
    } else {
        sideNav.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

menuButton.addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

Comment: for this you should use classes instead of ids

Comment: give them all a class of "toggle" or something

Comment: No, you don't need any constructors: you don't want to construct any objects. Just put the whole thing in a (normal) function, with parameters for the things (ids? elements?) that differ, and call it as often as you need.

Comment: or you could just pass the id into your function.

Comment: It is a single button that show/hide many elements at once, or a button for every element?

Comment: Calvin it's a button for every element. That's why I can use the same class for buttons as some are suggesting (I don't want to toggle everything at once).

Comment: @Bergi - I'm not sure how to get the parameters to connect to the variables, and if I use parameters, I think that limits me to 3 instances, I want to be able to create as many instances as needed. Thanks for the response though

Comment: @AshleyBrandon Connect to which variables? Where does the number 3 come from? No, you should be able to call the function as often as you want. What exactly you should pass as an argument depends on your needs. Can you post an example (including some markup) where you need to deal with multiple buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look, see if this helps you.
I did it with vanilla JS, I don't know if you are currently using jQuery (would be easier if yes)

What I did:
Every button have it's own `id` that is used to "connect" to the elements that it should toggle.

1. First I add the listener to all buttons, passing it's id when the function is called.
2. Then in the function, I used `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements with the class that should be hidden/show.
3. Then finally I run a loop in those elements, showing or not showing, depending on it's current 'display'.

```js
var menuButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.menuButton');
menuButtons.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener("click", toggle.bind(this, btn.id));
})

function toggle(id) {
    var sideNav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_' + id);
    sideNav.forEach(function(el){
      if (el.style.display == 'none'){
        el.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        el.style.display = "none"
      }
    })
}
```

```css
div{
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  background: #999;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<button id="menuButton1" class="menuButton">Toggle 1</button>
<button id="menuButton2" class="menuButton">Toggle 2</button>
<button id="menuButton3" class="menuButton">Toggle 3</button>

<div class="nav_menuButton1">1</div>
<div class="nav_menuButton1">1</div>
<div class="nav_menuButton2">2</div>
<div class="nav_menuButton3">3</div>
<div class="nav_menuButton3">3</div>
<div class="nav_menuButton3">3</div>
```

Probably there are better approaches, but I'm now in a hurry and this is the best I could think in that moment

Answer (score -1):

Use JQuery to obtain it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menuButton').click(toggle);
});


function toggle(){
    $('.toggle-item').each(function(){
            $(this).show();
    })
}
```

and for all you items, add the `toggle-item` class with this css:

```
.toggle-item{
  display: none;
}
```

If for every button there is an item to show, this is the way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menuButton').each(function(){
        var button = $(this);
        button.click(function(){
          toggle(button.attr('data-target')));
        });
    });
});


function toggle(itemId){
    $(itemId).show();
}
```

Adding this attribute to button:

```
<button class="menuButton" data-target="#toggle-item-1"></button>
```

Comment: You can just call `$('.toggle-item').show()` to show all of them

Comment: if asker uses jQuery... He didn't mentioned/tagged anything about jQuery

Comment: True, but is a lot more simple with JQuery

Comment: @Frighi Something as simple as toggling visibility is hardly made simpler by introducing a monstrous library such as jQuery

Comment: [You should use jquery for that](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/25mp2k/you_should_use_jquery_for_that/)

Comment: LOL, anyway developing websites, sooner or later JQuery could save your time, mostly if you doesen't have good knowledge of JS basic